# Trouble deciphering Autobench output

Tags: benchmarking, autobench, httperf

I'm trying to benchmark a simple webserver I wrote, but I'm having trouble deciphering what Autobench has outputted.  I've been googling all over for help on this (even going through the autobench and httperf source code) but haven't been able to grok what's going on.

I ran the following benchmark on my server:

```
autobench --single_host --host1 10.0.1.5 --port1 5555 --uri1 /Tests --quiet --low_rate 20 --high_rate 200 --rate_step 20 --num_call 10 --num_conn 5000 --timeout 5 --file results.csv
```

Here's my results.csv file (with some extra whitespace for readability):

```
dem_req_rate,req_rate,con_rate,min_rep_rate,avg_rep_rate,max_rep_rate,stddev_rep_rate,resp_time,net_io,errors
200,         40.0,    20.0,    20.0,        20.0,        20.0,        0.0,            6.2,      15.6,  100
400,         80.0,    40.0,    40.0,        40.0,        40.0,        0.0,            6.4,      31.2,  100
600,         119.9,   60.0,    57.0,        59.9,        61.4,        0.9,            17.9,     46.8,  100.160256410256
800,         159.5,   79.9,    76.0,        79.5,        82.4,        2.1,            32.5,     62.1,  100.48231511254
1000,        155.9,   94.0,    55.8,        64.7,        75.8,        6.2,            129.4,    50.4,  151.975683890577
1200,        156.7,   112.6,   28.0,        45.5,        63.2,        11.3,           148.0,    38.9,  255.232261357836
1400,        154.7,   121.8,   22.2,        38.1,        51.6,        9.3,            175.6,    34.2,  328.299409061064
1600,        154.5,   134.7,   15.6,        28.7,        52.8,        13.3,           211.6,    27.7,  498.504486540379
1800,        143.5,   138.7,   3.2,         18.6,        41.0,        11.7,           185.1,    21.1,  768.049155145929
2000,        158.8,   159.4,   5.6,         18.0,        45.6,        14.6,           234.7,    21.6,  925.925925925926
```

I'm wondering:

What does `dem_req_rate` mean?  What does `net_io` mean?  What does `errors` mean?  How does `errors` relate to `dem_req_rate`?  What units are all of these in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I also searched for it:

- `dem_req_rate = num_call * curr_rate` 
  where `curr_rate` is the rate passed to `httperf` depending on the iteration number and the setting of `rate_step`, `low_rate` and `high_rate` params ([**man autobench**](http://www.xenoclast.org/autobench/man/autobench.html) for more on those params)
- `net_io` = the average network throughput in kilobytes per second KB/s
   
  is  the `Net I/O` from `httperf` from the `Miscellaneous Section` of its output and **man page**(not linked)
- `errors` is the `Total errors` from the `Errors Section` of `httperf` results and its **man page**(not linked)

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I wonder what 'dem' stands for in dem_req_rate. Same question for min_rep_rate, what does 'rep' stands for?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just `man httperf`
you will find detail info.

Answer (score 0):

Errors is supposed to be the % of errors, but in the version of autobench I have (2.1.1) the value is calculated incorrectly.

It is:

```
$results{percent_errors} = ( 100 * $results{errors} / $results{replies} );
```

It should be:

```
$results{percent_errors} = ( 100 * $results{errors} / ($results{replies} + $results{errors}) );
```